# Driver constraint addon error when it is applied : property has not been found

Tags: armature, bones, constraints, drivers, shape-keys

I used the **driver constraint addon** to connect the **shapekeys** to the **bones**. The shapekeys come from the **manuel bastioni lab** and the bones from **rigify**. I've used two armatures and I have connected them into one only armature called rig. Now I'm trying to use the addon to constraint the bones because I want that when I use the shapekeys also the bones move. The final goal is to convert the **shapekeys library** into a **pose library** faster. The problem is that when I go on a shapekey and I do "**copy data path"**,the value copied is not good and it can't be used with the driver contraint addon. It sounds like this : **active_shape_key_index** ; instead this value should return the name of the shakepey. Anyway,when I use this value the error given is : **"bpy_structdriver_add() properly "active_shape_key_index" not animatable".** Instead,If i use the name of the shapekeys,the error is **"property has not been found"**.

You can watch what happens going here : (also the blender file is there)

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1E4mUhKuKBTZQoIwfnWIGcV6xp8NSgqxb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you made a little mistake in the process of setting up the driver.

You need to copy the datapath of the value. Not the shapekey name. You need to rightclick on the digits and then copy the datapath.

That should do the trick. Then the addon should recognize that you want to key the shapekey value.

Comment: Howdy ndee. Can you elaborate a little on this?, particularly on the data_path.

Comment: The correct data path is my case is on the value field,not on the shapekey name field. But it seems that in your tutorial you have taken this value from the shapekey name field. watch at 29s of your tutorial :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OV0gcfXQgAQ&t=29s

Comment: this is the reply that manuel bastioni gave to me : 
After finalization,the characters of the lab become standard models, so (apart from the use of the "after creation tools") they are no longer linked to the lab and usually the generic problems depend on Blender or the other addons. To be sure I did this test: starting from an empty scene I created a cube and added a shapekey: also in this case the copy data path always gives me the same "active_shape_key_index", so it would seem to be a generalized behavior of Blender.

Comment: @batFINGER
The DriverConstraint Addon takes a data_path of an object value and that way it can create a driver for that particular value. The addon supports almost any property. By having a dual selection of object and for example a bone, the addon sets everything up for you.

Comment: @Marietto
In the video I rightclick on the value. It should work with any rig. You can even use other objects transormations as driver for values.
Did you get it to work?

Comment: @ndee : I need to talk privately to you about your addon. I'm trying to contact you in a lot of ways but you rarely answer. That's because it does not work properly for me,at least for what I need to do,even if it remains indispensable.

Comment: no. it does not work for me.

Comment: Looks like another cool addon. comment  twas more a prod to edit your answer with some more details, eg a before / after screenshot

Comment: check these pics and you will see that you have clicked on the shapekey name,not on his value : https://ibb.co/fyB9Xd ; https://ibb.co/ng2SJJ

Comment: I have also need to modify the addon to make it work also for this situation : https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/109869/how-to-convert-the-shapekey-movement-to-a-pose-movement-with-the-driver-costrai ; I want that the shapekey drives the bone,I don’t want that the bone drives the shapekey.

Comment: @Marietto do you have a working example of driving bone with shapekey?  If the bone is also from the rig that modifies the mesh via armature modifier this could create one hell of a cyclic redundancy.

Comment: I created this and it works good : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qQsRtv4WTD5wUkHHNhgXyFwyMlSjLpVg