# how to use the slider of the shapekey value for moving the shapekey and the bone connected to it

Tags: armature, bones, constraints, drivers, shape-keys

I'm trying to connect the shapekeys that comes from the **manuel bastioni lab** to the bones that come from **rigify**. Infact I’ve used **two armatures** to get the best from both these rigging systems and I have connected them into **one only armature** that I have called rig.

I want that when I move the **value of the shapekeys expressions**, the bone should also move and both should deform the mesh.

I’ve watched some tutorials where the authors move the bones and the mesh connected with the shapekey also move. But I don’t need this.

I wanna move the slider of the value of the shapekey at the same time the bone that I have previously connected with the addon and the mesh should be deformed.

In my case,I have created a driver,but it does not work correctly,because a **cyclic dependency error.**

So,what’s the solution here ?

**I’m trying to convert the set of shapekeys of the manuel bastioni lab to a set of (bones) poses.**

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

Update : I configured the driver like this,but it does not work :

[image: 4]
[image: 5]
[image: 6]

update 2 : After having tried to follow the **kraken** suggestion,I have solved half problem,but not everything. Infact now with the child of contraint I'm able to move the bone through the shapekey value,but when I add a pose on the poselib it sticks but I can't clear the transformations. Just need to fix this...check the video below to understand..

[video to show that the clear transformations don't work](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1P4sf5TBSnsQIkDlowgVshkqg58ynLCqC)

Comment: Are you still getting the cyclic dependancy warning?

Comment: no,check here : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1DuL732qyuoaKNXwnphVL90Nekx5ODK2E

Comment: The bit under "_Dependency Cycle Detected_"??

Comment: what do yo u mean ?

Comment: I mean,yes,I'm getting the cyclic dependancy warning even if I have enabled the new depsgraph. do you know why ?

Comment: If the bones are part of the armature deforming the mesh, and the shape key is part of that mesh driving a bone in fore-said armature ==> dependency cycle.

Comment: So,the approach used is totally wrong and I need to find another way to achieve my goal.

Comment: In this case, my gut feeling  is yes. Haven't been doing much rigging recently... for some time,  I do remember trying to get around dependency cycles is tricky, and often ends up a cycle again.  Suggest creating and linking a simple example file., often helps in the hunt for answers.

Comment: what are the worse consequences that could happens because these dependencies cycles ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the constraints modifier add a "child of" constraint to the bone you want mimimicing the target/parent bone.  You can influence the amount of mimic of this bone with the constraint, as the target bone controls the overall movement of child bone.

I assume you already have the vertex group assigned to the parent bone and its shape keys.   You should be able to use those defined values while adding the child constraint.

Good Luck.

Comment: After having tried to follow your suggestion,I have solved almost everything,but not everything. Infact now with the child of constraint I'm able to move the bone through the shapekey value,but when I add a pose on the poselib it sticks but I can't clear the transformations. Just need to fix this...check the video added above to understand..

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to mention.  the Cube in the file is the parent of the sphere.  If you move the cube, the sphere follows.  If you change the constraint modifier of the sphere to .5 it will follow half as much.      This method can be applied to your bones so that one bone controls another bone which controls the face.

Comment: Instead of adding another answer which doesn't differ in content, edit your answer to include the additional information.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is not possible with Blender's current dependency graph. The dependency graph is being refactored for release later this year as part of 2.8. You can enable a beta version in 2.79 by running Blender using the argument:

```
--enable-new-depsgraph
```

If you're on Windows, right click on your Blender desktop icon, click properties and add the above to the end of the "Target" path. This may allow you to do what you want without creating a dependency cycle.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the two side bones don't move correctly when using the pose library. Try to include them in the pose